# Asp.NET Mvc 4 Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a blog in mvc 4 and trying make a route .

Here is how it looks now:

```
/About/Index
```

But I'd like it to look like:

```
/About/Firstname-Lastname
```

The firstname and lastname is always the same; it's not supposed to be dynamic. Here is what I have so far. I know it is because it needs to know what view show. So is there a way to say if /About/Firstname-Lastname then show Index?

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "About",
            url: "{controller}/{name}/",
            defaults:
                new
                    {
                        controler = "About",
                        action =  UrlParameter.Optional,
                        name = "firstname-Lastname"

                    }
            );
```

Comment: I don't believe the action can be optional. The route has to know which method on the controller to invoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "About",
    url: "About/Anne-Refsgaard/",
    defaults:
        new
            {
                controler = "About",
                action =  "Index",
            }
    );
```

This route needs to be added before the standard route

Comment: Looks like you were faster =)

Comment: Have allready tried that but just tried it again to be 100% sure i still get 404 on /About/First-Name but i hit when i request /About/Index

Comment: @MikkelRefsgaard: this route need to be added BEFORE default route. Have you done that?

Comment: @Andre Calil: It happens to all of us ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "FirstnameLastname",
                url: "about/Andre-Calil",
                defaults: new { controller = "About", action = "Index" }
            );
```

Remember that the order of the routes matter. The first route that accepts the request will be used.

Comment: @ChadRuppert There is no parameter, OP stated that `Firstname-Lastname` are fixed values. OP simply wants to modify the URL, after all. This is no joke answer.

Comment: yeah, i removed my comment after I noticed that. and upvoted instead of down